# Textview will not add text on load

Tags: ios, uitextview

I've been spending hours trying to get my textview to load with text from a string when loading but it always appears blank but when I do it through button action it works fine.

Is this a known issue or is there even a solution?

Here is the code.  NSLog does show the string contents.

```
Variables *GetVariables = [Variables SharedInstance];
NSString *Text = GetVariables.FileText;
NSLog(@"%@", Text);
_MyTextField.text = Text;
```

Comment: Never seen it. Post codes.

Comment: Ur code should have worked. Try this. Textfield.text = [NSstring stringwithformat:@"%@",getvariables.filetext];  sorry abt format from mobile.

Comment: Thats the thing i have tried this and still not working.

Comment: I'm doing this in view will appear if this helps.

Comment: Make sure `_MyTextField` is not `nil`.

Comment: And also make sure `GetVariables` and `Text` are not nil.

Comment: What will checking if textfield is nill do any differently?

Comment: It might tell you what's wrong. Either your _MyTextField property is nil or your Text is nil. You need to figure out which. BTW, you should stick to Objective-C naming conventions, and start your property names with lowercase letters. Where in your app do you have this code?

Comment: Property is declared in .h but the code is in viewdidappear

Comment: Did you check if either _MyTextField or Text is nil (by logging or with the debugger)?

Comment: Just checked and Text is not nil but _MyTextField is coming up as nil.  What could this mean?

Comment: is that textField an outlet from nib or storyboard? and what about loading textfield in view did load?